# Dealing with different versions of the same dependency

Tags: c#, .net-core

So i just installed Entity Framework Profiler, and when i Started my Web app, and made my first request, Hangfire suddenly couldn't find System.Data.SqlClient.
It turns out that the System.Data.SqlClient required by the Entity Framework Profiler was 4.2.0.2 and the version required by Hangfire was 4.2.0.0.
So now i have to different libraries that i have no control over, depending on the same library, but 2 different versions.

I get the error:

```
       (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) -> 
     C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Data.SqlClient" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
```

So i looked in the buildlog and found little more info than what the above error stated, except what libraries, had that dependency.

Looking through the log, it does state that it can't find the 4.2.0.2 file, but later i get the conflict:

```
         Dependency "System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
         Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
         Required by "HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender".
```

The conflict:

```
         There was a conflict between "System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
         "System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
```

Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: Depending on which version of .net you are on (which you don't mention but I am guessing .net framework), this might be fixable through binding redirects.

Comment: didn't realize the version was relevant. I've added .net-core tag. it's .net core 3

Answer (score 0):

See if adding this binding redirect helps. I am assuming you are running on .net framework.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlClient" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.2.0.0-4.2.0.2" newVersion="4.2.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, i am actually running .net core 3. Didn't realize that was relevant.

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was that one of the libraries, i added as a reference manually, when i added it via NuGet, the problem was gone.
It seems NuGet, handles theses references alot better.